# Starting user units from custom path

Tags: rhel, multiuser, units

I have successfully enabled user units in RHEL 8 under ~/.config/systemd/user directory. Enabling linger also gives me the option to start the service without having to login. My question, is it possible to have user units, namely .service files, located at a different path other than ~/.config/systemd/user and still be able to start these user units just like I am able to do now?

Comment: I love that you paradoxically started your question with "I’ll try to get straight to the point." instead of, you know, getting straight to the point :D !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible; `man systemd.unit` is your friend and helper here!

```
   User Unit Search Path
       ~/.config/systemd/user.control/*
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/user.control/*
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/transient/*
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator.early/*
       ~/.config/systemd/user/*
       $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/systemd/user/*
       /etc/systemd/user/*
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/user/*
       /run/systemd/user/*
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator/*
       $XDG_DATA_HOME/systemd/user/*
       $XDG_DATA_DIRS/systemd/user/*
       ...
       /usr/lib/systemd/user/*
       $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator.late/*
```

and

> The set of load paths for the user manager instance may be augmented or changed using various environment variables. And environment variables may in turn be set using environment generators, see systemd.environment-
> generator(7). In particular, $XDG_DATA_HOME and $XDG_DATA_DIRS may be easily set using systemd-environment-d-generator(8). Thus, directories listed here are just the defaults. To see the actual list that would be used
> based on compilation options and current environment use
>
> ```
> systemd-analyze --user unit-paths
> ```
>
> Moreover, additional units might be loaded into systemd from directories not on the unit load path by creating a symlink pointing to a unit file in the directories. You can use systemctl link for this; see systemctl(1).
> The file system where the linked unit files are located must be accessible when systemd is started (e.g. anything underneath /home/ or /var/ is not allowed, unless those directories are located on the root file system).

---

Now  the interesting question here is whether what you describe *should* be *user* unit files, or whether you might actually be looking to install a *system* service unit file which is run as your user.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I need to add a new environment where I have all of my services, I should be using $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, correct?